# .kv is loaded multiples times, you might have unwanted behaviors

Tags: kivy, kivymd

I can run my code but I'm having such unwanted behavior [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXTh2.png), I combined my source code with the https://dev.to/ngonidzashe/how-to-create-a-simple-to-do-list-application-with-kivymd-d89 , and I guess I didn't combine it right here are my code:

```
import mysql.connector
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker
from datetime import datetime
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineAvatarIconListItem, ILeftBodyTouch
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox
from database import Database
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (350, 600)

db = Database()

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        global screen_manager
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("login.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("register.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("main.kv"))
        return screen_manager

    database = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                       database='loginform',
                                       user='root',
                                       password='****')
    cursor = database.cursor()

    def send_data(self, user, password):
        self.cursor.execute(f"insert into example2 values('{user.text}','{password.text}')")
        self.database.commit()

    def receive_data(self, user, password):
        self.cursor.execute("select * from example2")
        user_list = []
        for i in self.cursor.fetchall():
            user_list.append(i[0])
        if user.text in user_list and user.text != "":
            self.cursor.execute(f"select password from example2 where user='{user.text}'")
            for j in self.cursor:
                if password.text == j[0]:
                    open_button = MDFlatButton(text='Open the App', on_release=self.open_app)
                    close_button = MDFlatButton(text='Close', on_release=self.close_dialg)
                    self.dialog = MDDialog(text='Welcome to the *****',
                                           buttons=[close_button, open_button])
                    self.dialog.open()

                else:
                    try_button = MDFlatButton(text='Try Again', on_release=self.close_dialg)
                    self.dialog = MDDialog(title='Incorrect Password',
                                           text='You entered wrong password please try again',
                                           buttons=[try_button])
                    self.dialog.open()
        else:
            open_regist = MDFlatButton(text="Register", on_release=self.open_regist)
            close_button = MDFlatButton(text='Close', on_release=self.close_dialg)
            self.dialog = MDDialog(title='Incorrect User',
                                   text='There are no such user',
                                   buttons=[close_button, open_regist])
            self.dialog.open()

    def open_regist(self, *args):
        screen_manager.current = "register"
        self.dialog.dismiss()

    def close_dialg(self, *args):
        self.dialog.dismiss()

    def open_app(self, *args):
        screen_manager.current = "tasks"
        self.dialog.dismiss()

    task_list_dialog = None  # Here

    # Add the below functions
    def show_task_dialog(self):
        if not self.task_list_dialog:
            self.task_list_dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Create Task",
                type="custom",
                content_cls=DialogContent(),
            )

        self.task_list_dialog.open()

    def on_start(self):
        """Load the saved tasks and add them to the MDList widget when the application starts"""
        try:
            completed_tasks, uncomplete_tasks = db.get_tasks()

            if uncomplete_tasks != []:
                for task in uncomplete_tasks:
                    add_task = ListItemWithCheckbox(pk=task[0], text=task[1], secondary_text=task[2])
                    self.root.ids.container.add_widget(add_task)

            if completed_tasks != []:
                for task in completed_tasks:
                    add_task = ListItemWithCheckbox(pk=task[0], text='[s]' + task[1] + '[/s]',
                                                    secondary_text=task[2])
                    add_task.ids.check.active = True
                    self.root.ids.container.add_widget(add_task)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass

    def close_dialog(self, *args):
        self.task_list_dialog.dismiss()

    def add_task(self, task, task_date):
        """Add task to the list of tasks"""

        # Add task to the db
        created_task = db.create_task(task.text, task_date)  # Here

        # return the created task details and create a list item
        self.root.ids['container'].add_widget(
            ListItemWithCheckbox(pk=created_task[0], text='[b]' + created_task[1] + '[/b]',
                                 secondary_text=created_task[2]))  # Here
        task.text = ''


class DialogContent(MDBoxLayout):
    """OPENS A DIALOG BOX THAT GETS THE TASK FROM THE USER"""

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # set the date_text label to today's date when user first opens dialog box
        self.ids.date_text.text = str(datetime.now().strftime('%A %d %B %Y'))

    def show_date_picker(self):
        """Opens the date picker"""
        date_dialog = MDDatePicker()
        date_dialog.bind(on_save=self.on_save)
        date_dialog.open()

    def on_save(self, instance, value, date_range):
        """This functions gets the date from the date picker and converts its it a
        more friendly form then changes the date label on the dialog to that"""

        date = value.strftime('%A %d %B %Y')
        self.ids.date_text.text = str(date)


# create the following two classes
class ListItemWithCheckbox(TwoLineAvatarIconListItem):
    """Custom list item"""

    def __init__(self, pk=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # state a pk which we shall use link the list items with the database primary keys
        self.pk = pk

    def mark(self, check, the_list_item):
        """mark the task as complete or incomplete"""
        if check.active == True:
            # add strikethrough to the text if the checkbox is active
            the_list_item.text = '[s]' + the_list_item.text + '[/s]'
            db.mark_task_as_complete(the_list_item.pk)  # here
        else:
            the_list_item.text = str(db.mark_task_as_incomplete(the_list_item.pk))  # Here

    def delete_item(self, the_list_item):
        """Delete the task"""
        self.parent.remove_widget(the_list_item)
        db.delete_task(the_list_item.pk)  # Here


class LeftCheckbox(ILeftBodyTouch, MDCheckbox):
    """Custom left container"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

and here is my kv file with this:

```
MDScreen:
    name: "tasks"
    MDFloatLayout:
        MDLabel:
            id: task_label
            halign: 'center'
            markup: True
            text: "[u][size=48][b]TASKS[/b][/size][/u]"
            pos_hint: {'y': .45}

        ScrollView:
            pos_hint: {'center_y': .5, 'center_x': .5}
            size_hint: .9, .8

            MDList:
                id: container

        MDFloatingActionButton:
            icon: 'plus-thick'
            on_release: app.show_task_dialog() #functionality to be added later
            elevation_normal: 12
            pos_hint: {'x': .8, 'y':.05}
<DialogContent>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "10dp"
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: "130dp"

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1

        MDTextField:
            id: task_text
            hint_text: "Add Task..."
            pos_hint: {"center_y": .4}
            max_text_length: 50
            on_text_validate: (app.add_task(task_text, date_text.text), app.close_dialog())

        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'calendar'
            on_release: root.show_date_picker()
            padding: '10dp'

    MDLabel:
        spacing: '10dp'
        id: date_text

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "SAVE"
            on_release: (app.add_task(task_text, date_text.text), app.close_dialog())
        MDFlatButton:
            text: 'CANCEL'
            on_release: app.close_dialog()
<ListItemWithCheckbox>:
    id: the_list_item
    markup: True

    LeftCheckbox:
        id: check
        on_release:
            root.mark(check, the_list_item)

    IconRightWidget:
        icon: 'trash-can-outline'
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        on_release:
            root.delete_item(the_list_item)
```

I would be very thankful if someone can help or give some tips, how to improve. I'm open to have private conversation.

Answer (score 0):

A `kv` file with the name `main.kv` will be loaded automatically by Kivy for your application (See [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv)). So your code:

```
screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("main.kv"))
```

is loading `main.kv` a second time. The easiest fix is to just rename the `main.kv` file.

Comment: Thank you it helped, now there's issue with 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__', and when I'm trying to save my task it says, line 122, in add_task
     self.root.ids['container'].add_widget(
 KeyError: 'container' , 
if I delete <''> from container it won't define it and not works how can I solve it?

Comment: The `container` `id` is defined in the `MDScreen` (named `tasks), so the `KeyError` come from trying to access that `id` from the `root` widget, which is not the `MDScreen`. You probably need to access that `id` as `self.root.get_screen('tasks').ids.container`.

Comment: Thank you that worked for me but I started to receive ' TypeError: 'kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy' object is not callable' this kind of error. Can you please help me @JohnAnderson

Comment: Sounds like that should be asked as a new question.